# Copy and pasted graphics are fuzzy

Tags: graphics, front-end, interoperability, windows, office

I have a function that creates a 2D line with filling to the axis. When I copy this graphic into MS Word it is very fuzzy, so much so that the numbers and text are almost unreadable, not to mention the aesthetic problem.

When I take away the filling, the graphic can be copy and pasted into word as normal.

the code used is:

```
Show[
  Plot[d[x], {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> {-0.003, 0.003}], 
  ListLinePlot[residualsdata, PlotStyle -> Black, Filling -> Axis, 
    FillingStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.5], Green]]]
```

The graphic without the filling is gotten by:

```
Show[
  Plot[d[x], {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> {-0.003, 0.003}], 
  ListLinePlot[residualsdata, PlotStyle -> Black]]
```

Does anybody know the cause of this problem and/or how to fix it?

Comment: Is this Word 2010? You might need to convert the picture to a drawing object - right click on the fuzzy picture, select Edit Picture, then Yes.

Comment: It would also help if we knew what `d[x]` was.

Comment: The most likely cause is that the default copy format (EMF?) doesn't support transparency and therefore as soon as you add the filling, Mathematica will copy in a different format (likely bitmap).  You ca experiment with Edit -> Copy As ad choose different formats and see which one gives good results.  However, for the best possible result in Word, I'd recommend exporting to PNG using the `Export` command and a high `ImageResoltuion` setting.

Comment: Well, for LaTeX PDF/EPS are likely yo give better quality ... except for 3D graphics.

Comment: Related MathGroups thread: "[Mathematica 8 Windows EMF/WMF export with transparent background?](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/jW3p6k0u6SM/Pjpw7_Fp2z8J)"

Answer (score 3):

The most likely cause is that the default copy format (EMF?) doesn't support transparency and therefore as soon as you add the filling, Mathematica will copy in a different format (likely bitmap). You ca experiment with Edit -> Copy As and choose different formats and see which one gives good results. However, for the best possible result in Word, I'd recommend exporting to PNG using the `Export` command and a high `ImageResolution` setting.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to rasterization [suggested by Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/40115/280) is to insert in the Word document not a [metafile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Metafile) (which you do by default by selecting graphics in the FrontEnd, copying and pasting it in MS Word) but an EPS vector image with flattened **vector** transparency and *Mathematica* fonts embedded in it (it has additional [advantage of independence from *Mathematica* fonts](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38715/280)). It is slightly more difficult because *Mathematica*'s EPS export is rudimentary and you will need to `Export` your graphics to PDF first, then use Adobe software to flatten transparency and create EPS **level 2** file from the exported PDF. But it is worth the effort because this way allows you to achieve the best possible vector quality for printing purposes. [Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32948/280) I discuss how to do it using Adobe Illustrator or Adobe Acrobat and [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/98635/280) contains additional explanations.

Answer (score 0):

I've similarly wrestled with this problem for years. I'm not sure how to fix it in general, but one possible culprit for you is `Opacity`. For me the plot here (not the most simple example)

```
ListPlot[
    {{0, 4.5}, {40, 4.5}},
    PlotStyle -> {Lighter[Purple], Opacity[0.5]}, Joined -> True,
    Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"Endurance (min)", "Payload (kg)"}
]
```

is blurry when I print it or otherwise save it as a .pdf file. However, if you remove the `Opacity[0.5]` it is crisp.