# Exporting 2D & 3D graphics for use in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: graphics3d, export, pdf-format, interoperability, compatibility

I have recently (perhaps since *Mathematica* Version 10?) encountered a change in how PDF images are saved and how they behave after being loaded into Adobe Illustrator (v16.0.4 under Mac OS X 10.10.5).

In short: for 2D graphics, Illustrator can edit the graphics--all elements
are accessible. For 3D graphics, some rasterization of the graphics is all
that is in the exported PDF, and so individual elements cannot be edited in Illustrator.

Here are examples. First, simple 2D graphics:

```
g = Graphics[
  Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]]
```

Export from Mathematica to PDF. Open in Illustrator. (Or just copy the graphic from Mathematica and paste into Illustrator.) Then the elements can
be edited. Here is a snapshot from Illustrator:

---

[image: AI2D]

---

Now, 3D graphics:

```
g = Graphics3D[
   Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1/2}}]
   ,Boxed -> False];
Export["PDFTestExport.pdf", g, "PDF"]
```

This is what it looks like within Mathematica:

---

[image: MmaFig3D]

---

Opening the exported PDF in Illustrator reads in a rasterization,
as this snapshot in Illustrator shows:

---

[image: AI3DRaster]

---

I tried following
[@Szabolcs suggestion in
another thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/88922/194) to use Preview to resave the PDF, but this didn't change matters.

I certainly used to be able to even copy from 3D Mathematica graphics,
and paste into Illustrator, with full ability to edit the elements in Illustrator. So something has changed as various software has progressed
through newer versions (Mathematica, Illustrator, Mac OS X).
I would love the regain that useful editing capability. If anyone has ideas, I would appreciate hearing them.

(Incidentally, exporting to EPS is not a solution: All such files crash my version of Illustrator upon opening.)

Comment: Even opening in Acrobat, you can see image is rasterized. I think your best bet will be to export at high res & get paths in either photoshop or Illustrator - probably best in this instance do image processing from those platforms - see [here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/56960/21327) on GDSE.

Comment: @martin: Good point, this has nothing to do with Illustrator. It is just that 3D PDF exports from Mathematica now export rasterized images, whereas at some point in the past editable elements were exported. Thanks for the link to GDSE.

Comment: Try to add `"AllowRasterization" -> False` as an option to your `Export`. This option is mentioned somewhat cryptically in the MMA documentation to the PDF format, and it has been discussed in an older post on exporting PDF that actually wanted to achieve the exact opposite of what you want, i.e. rasterized 3D export:  [Exporting graphics to PDF - huge file](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1542/exporting-graphics-to-pdf-huge-file/1550#1550). Unfortunately I'm on a tablet and can't test it myself.

Comment: @MarcoB: Good idea, but it is still rasterized!

Comment: Sigh. I suspected as much. Unfortunately it seems that v.10 has introduced *enforced* rasterization of 3D graphics when exported to PDF. This has actually come up recently, and I had even participated in that discussion, but couldn't find it before: [Export Plot3D in MMA 10.1 is rasterized by default](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87733/export-plot3d-in-mathematica-10-1-is-rasterized-by-default) in which a partial workaround was proposed. I wonder if you could test that as well. I'm still on the tablet... :-)

Comment: @MarcoB: Brilliant! Amazingly, [Print Graphic](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/87753/194) works! Thanks so much!

Comment: I spoke too soon. `Print Graphic` worked for that simple one-polygon example, but for a more complex 3D plot, including transparency, `Print Graphic` rasterized. Hmm...

Comment: Ah, but without transparency, `Print Graphic` *does* save vector elements.

Comment: Hmm… should this behavior be regarded as a design change, a backslide, or a bug? @MarcoB

Comment: @xzczd Personally I consider it a backslide, but I think it’s really a design change. Others have argued on this site in favor of the change, as it produces more manageable images rather than complex vector expressions. I would contend that the vector expressions were better no matter their size and complexity, particularly considering how difficult it is at times to get reasonable rasterization results from MMA (ticks, text are not scaled correctly, etc.).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I consider this question pretty much answered by @MarcoB, as follows:

1. *Mathematica* 10 apparently forces rasterization by default when exporting 3D graphics to PDF, even when one adds the option `"AllowRasterization" -> False` to `Export`.
2. The only way to disable it is to use the `Inset` workaround [suggested by Jens](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/87753/280):

   ```
   Export["PDFTestExport.pdf", Graphics[Inset[g, Automatic, Automatic, Scaled[1]]]];
   ```

   Here is how the output is rendered by Adobe Acrobat:

[image: screenshot]

3. A [workaround via `Print Graphic`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/87753/194) (also suggested by @Jens) does export the vector elements for 3D graphics ...
4. ... unless the 3D graphic is too complex (e.g., includes transparency). Then even `Print Graphic` rasterizes.

Comment: Joseph, thank you for summarizing your findings here. This will be a useful cross-reference. (+1) I'd love to see somebody else come up with an alternative workaround, since being able to export `Graphics3D` results as vectors would make my day job a lot easier.

Comment: i cannot make it work in version 13