# How to save the output cell from this demonstration project as a .eps

Tags: export, cdf-format, eps-format, demonstrations

I'm having a lot of fun playing with this cool demonstration project by Karl Scherer:

http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/LineArt2/

After getting some beautiful artistic results I tried to print or save the output but sadly there doesn't appear to be a provision for this.  I'd love to save som .eps files that could be printed large to display.  What must be added/changed/modified in the code for this to be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`Paste Snapshot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IntroductionToManipulate.html#20842957) command from the [image: plus] menu of `Manipulate` for getting a static `DynamicModule` code of what you have created:

[image: screenshot]

For `Export`ing you can simply paste the code obtained via the `Paste Snapshot` command instead of `<code>` into the expression `Export["fig.eps", <code>]` (in another Notebook) and evaluated it. With *Mathematica* 10.4.1 I obtained this way a EPS file of size about 1 Mb. Note that [EPS format doesn't support semi-transparency](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32948/280) but the created figure contains `Opacity` directives. This means that obtained figure in the EPS format can differ from what you see in the Notebook.

Comment: For `Export`ing I just pasted the code obtained via the `Paste Snapshot` command instead of `<code>` into the expression `Export["fig.eps", <code>]` and evaluated it.

Comment: Got it thanks @Alexey Popkov !  FYI Eps does not provide a match when exporting the project output, only PDF works but it does work well!

Comment: Thanks for the Accept. It is [well-known](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32948/280) that EPS format does not support semi-transparency. A quick check confirmed that the output obtained from the CDF file contains `Opacity` directives, so they may be the reason for the mismatch.