# How could I perform Region or Polygon Clipping in mathematica?

Tags: regions, geometry, polygons

I need to clip several regions reg: like Rectangle, Polygon, Ellipse... 
My goal isn't to plot the clipping but to have a representation of each new region.

I searched if there was any package or function to perform polygon clipping at least, but I couldn't find any lead.

**My main question is:**

- **Is there an already implemented algorithm in mathematica to perform polygon or region clipping ?**

else:

- Should I better link an external polygon clipping library (such as Clipper, Boost.Geometry or CGAL) with mathematica to do so ?

**Edit:**

To illustrate what I aim for:

[image: Overlapping Rectangle]

I have 5 rectangles that are overlapping, I would like to have:

[image: Non-overlapping Regions]

I have now 8 regions that aren't intersecting/overlapping with others.

Comment: Are you looking for `RegionIntersection`?

Comment: I have edit my question to illustrate my problem. @Szabolcs It must in fact use `RegionIntersection`, but also `RegionDifference`... I tried a custom solution to do such result, but it's not working that well on any kind of polygons or regions disposition.

Comment: have you looked at `BooleanRegion` ?

Comment: Related: "[How do I flatten transparency on a graphics, for conversion to eps or similar?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29120/280)"

Answer (score 7):

Using boolean operations to test every possible combination of area intersections:

```
r1 = Disk[{0, 0}, 1];
r2 = Disk[{1/8, 0}, {1/2, 3/2}];
r3 = Rectangle[{1/4, 0}, {2, 1}];
regions={r1,r2,r3};
Graphics[{Opacity[.5], {{Red, r1}, {Green, r2}, {Blue, r3}}}]
```

[image]

```
range = {{-2,2},{-2,2}};
(*warning RegionPlot throws errors
    if nothing is in the plot range*)
sub[set_, r_] := 
 Module[{
   in = Flatten@Position[set, 1], 
   out = Flatten@Position[set, 0]}, 
  If[Union@set === {1}, RegionIntersection @@ r, 
   RegionDifference[
      BooleanRegion[And, r[[in]]], 
      BooleanRegion[Or, r[[out]]]]]]
c = Tuples[{0, 1}, Length@regions][[2 ;;]]; (*dont include first tuple {0,0,..}*)
subregions = Select[sub[#, regions] & /@ c, Area@# > 0 &];
s = MapThread[RegionPlot[#1, PlotStyle -> #2, PlotRange -> range] &,
   {subregions, 
    Table[Hue[RandomReal[{0, 2/3}]], {Length@subregions}]}];
Grid[{s, c}]
Show[s, PlotRange -> range]
```

[image]

[image]

notice there are disconnected sub regions that happen when a single region is split by the others. Kind of stumped on how to split those automatically into separate regions.

edit per comment from @JasonB we can get all the discrete regions, but it requires generating mesh regions:

```
  ConnectedMeshComponents@DiscretizeRegion[#] & /@ subregions
```

[image]

edit:
the example

```
regions = {Rectangle[{5, -15}, {35, 15}], 
   Rectangle[{25, -20}, {45, 20}], Rectangle[{20, -5}, {35, 5}], 
   Rectangle[{30, 10}, {45, 20}], Rectangle[{35, -20}, {45, -5}]};
range = {{0, 50}, {-30, 30}}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply @george2079 However, c variable definition is missing, what is the `set_` arguments for ?

Comment: sort for the excessive editing... now its working right..! excepting for the pesky issue of how to split the disconnected regions.

Comment: @george2079 - you can use [ConnectedMeshComponents](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConnectedMeshComponents.html)

Comment: @JasonB, thanks - added that.

Comment: @george2079 I've tried your code on my example  `regions = {Rectangle[{5, -15}, {35, 15}], Rectangle[{25, -20}, {45, 20}], 
 Rectangle[{20, -5}, {35, 5}], Rectangle[{30, 10}, {45, 20}], 
 Rectangle[{35, -20}, {45, -5}]}` and I have issues with `RegionPlot::nnregion` and `RegionPlot::nnregion`

Comment: making me work!..  Two fixes needed: use `Area` to eliminate empty regions. Also the `PlotRange` was hard coded.

Comment: Thanks a lot @george2079, working pretty well now !