# How to plot .eps and make it can be opened by Illustrator?

Tags: export, eps-format

```
Export["C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\example.eps", 
ContourPlot[(x^2 + (y + 1)^2 - 2)^3 == x^2*(y + 1)^3, {x, -3.2, 
 3.2}, {y, -3.2, 3.2}, PlotPoints -> 400, MaxRecursion -> 10, 
ContourStyle -> {Black}, Axes -> False, Frame -> False, 
ImageSize -> {1000, 1000}], ImageResolution -> 300]
```

But I could not use Illustrator and Inkscape to open `example.eps`.
How to solve this problem?

Comment: Export as PDF for Illustrator and as SVG for Inkscape.

Comment: Also you can use the Place command of Illustrator for opening EPS as I describe [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32948/280) (see at the bottom).

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov,even export as PDF, when I open .pdf in illustrator, can only get half of the image.