# Problem importing a pdf with a character with increasing opacity

Tags: bugs, import, pdf-format, opacity

I want to import a pdf in MMA(ver 12.0).
The pdf is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13756stnYKBcz9CYPuemYq7KT6l07J2hr/view?usp=sharing).
This pdf has a "$c^2$" in the middle of the white square that is completely transparent in the first page, then it become progressively more opaque in the following pages.

This is an image of page 1:
[image: Import PDF problem page 1]

This is an image of page 5:
[image: Import PDF problem page 5]

This is an image of page 11 (last page):
[image]

And this is the result of the importation of the same pages with mma (ver. 12.0)

```
Import["DimAnim.pdf",{"Pages",{1,5,11}}]
```

[image: Import withh mma]

As you can see, the "$c^2$" is completely opaque in all pages imported in mma.

Is this a bug?

Is there a workaround?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reproduce the problem with *Mathematica* 12.1 on Windows 10 x64: the transparency information is lost. It is a bug, please report it to the support.

I've found a simple workaround working perfectly in this concrete case: I simply opened the file with Adobe Acrobat and then printed it to the "Microsoft Print to PDF" virtual printer (in the Print dialog I've checked "[Choose paper source by PDF page size](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/basic-pdf-printing-tasks.html#id_96641)"). A PDF file obtained this way looks exactly as the original and is imported correctly by *Mathematica* 12.1:

```
Show[#, PlotRange -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Medium] & /@ 
 Import["DimAnim_printed.pdf", {"Pages", {1, 5, 11}}]
```

[image: screenshot]

Note that in this PDF file transparency is completely flattened (it contains no transparent objects).

I've also tried printing to the "Adobe PDF" virtual printer, and found that *Mathematica* incorrectly imports a PDF file, obtained this way despite the fact that it also contains no transparent objects (transparency is flattened):

[image: screenshot2]

As one can see, "semi-transparent" (actually grey) letter "c" is imported as a rectangle (but is rendered correctly by Acrobat).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've made the bug report.