# Copy/Paste of a plot leaves whitespace

Tags: graphics, front-end, interoperability, windows

I'm trying to copy *Mathematica* figures into word, but when I do, I get tons of extra white-space for some reason. Either standard <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> - <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>p</kbd> or "copy graphic" does this.

I understand that I could export the figure as a graphic, open the png file, and copy it from there into my word document, but I feel like there must be a better way to do this. It's possible this is not a *Mathematica* issue, but I've only noticed this type of thing when copying pictures from *Mathematica*. Can anyone help?

[image: extra whitespace from *Mathematica*]

This problem occurs for me given even the most basic plot (e.g. `Plot[x,{x,-1,1}]`). I'm using **Mathematica 10.2 Student Edition** and the **Word 2016 Preview**. The Word 2016 preview might seem suspect, but I'm pretty sure I was having the exact same problem before with word 2013.

**Partial Solution**: I have no idea what the problem is with my system, but using **Copy as Bitmap** fixed this issue for me.

It still happens with **Copy as Metafile**.

Comment: Related: [(54708)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54708/280), [(38715)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38715/280).

Comment: I can not reproduce the extra white spaces using a simple `Plot`. You might add some code that creates a simplified `Plot` that can reproduce the behavior you observed.

Comment: Greetings! Make the most of Mma.SE and **take the [tour] now**. **Help us to help you**, write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimum** working examples of **code and data in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: I can NOT  reproduce your problem. Office 2007, Windows 7SP1 64bit. Tried **Copy as Bitmap** and **Copy as Metafile**. You should give more information about yous system and [formatted](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) code.

Comment: This problem occurs for me given even the most basic plot (e.g. Plot[x,{x,-1,1}]). I'm using Mathematica 10.2 Student Edition and the Word 2016 Preview. The word 2016 preview might seem suspect, but I'm pretty sure I was having the exact same problem before with word 2013.

Comment: @rhermans forgive my ignorance, but how do you copy as bitmap or as metafile in mathematica?

Comment: Edit > Copy As...> 
Last two options, look here:
http://i.stack.imgur.com/F2CHO.png

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem with *Mathematica* 10.2 and Word 2003 on Win7 x64.

Comment: @rhermans I still have no idea what my overall problem is and why it only seems to effect me, but "Copy as Bitmap" fixed the problem for me. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried pasting into some other software? You should [Edit] and update your question withe the new information. Please confirm that it does still happen if **Copy as Metafile.**

Comment: It still happens with copy as metafile.

Comment: I cannot confirm. With Mathematica 10.2 and Office 2016 I get
http://i.stack.imgur.com/y3IDG.gif

Comment: Maybe it is an OS-related issue? Which OS do you use?

Comment: Also are you using x86 or x64 version of MS Office?

Comment: @Alexey Popkov I am on Windows 10, Mathematica 10.2 and Office 2016. I have no problems in copying (ctl C) and pasting (ctl V) figures from Mathematica to Word 2016. The only thing I have to do is to justify the figure with a right mouseclick (text position and size).

Comment: My laptop is a x86 and MS Office is x32.

Comment: @aquirdturtle Which is your OS and of which bit depth your MS Office 2016 (x86 or x64)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29582/discussion-between-willinski-and-alexey-popkov).

Comment: Windows 10 does copying differently than previous OSes, and often doesn't play well with weird copy formats like images from Mathematica. Bitmap should work still, but I doubt this will be fixed with updates.

Comment: Because no one else reported reproducing the problem, I thought I'd comment that I'm having the very same white-space problem with regular 'Copy Graphic'. The problem seemed to appear out of nowhere--except that it did appear after I first used `Raster`. `yup = Graphics[ Raster[ImageData[yu, DataReversed -> True], {{Sqrt[Pi/2] - 0.07, -0.12}, {Sqrt[Pi/2] + 0.07, -0.05}}], Frame -> False]` Using Edit/Copy as/Bitmap does give a proper copy.