# Is ExportString defective in V11?

Tags: graphics, bugs, export, version-11

Mathematica doesn't do the best job of exporting figures with shading or transparency to vector graphics formats such as PDF.

A common trick employed here and elsewhere on the web to workaround this is to rasterize just the image portion of the figure and insert this back into a vector version of the axes, labels etc.

The axes are typically converted to a vector drawing by the command:

```
ImportString[ExportString[axes, "EPS"]]
```

However this appears to no longer work on V11. More specifically I'm not sure `ExportString[axes, "EPS"]]` is behaving as it should, certainly it's output is very different between V10 and V11.

Complete test case:

```
fig = Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}]
axes = Graphics3D[{}, AbsoluteOptions[fig]]
ExportString[axes, "EPS"]
```

Outputs at pastebin:

[V10](http://pastebin.com/xRzkW8V0), [V11](http://pastebin.com/A6gWQJYw)

The V10 output is all understandable and can be correctly imported via `ImportString` in both V10 and V11. However the V11 output contains what looks to be compressed data in the form

> ...g&[ie9oJbc5;SLF=49tG:f #EsI8)63Mg(KS!"/5i2neP :F"d@<>E99o

and cannot be imported by either V10 or V11.

So, am I missing something or is `ExportString[...,"EPS"]` not working correctly in V11?

If so, what is a suitable workaround?

**EDITS**

Note also that simply exporting to an EPS figure via `Export` also does not produce a vector image.

The option `"AllowRasterization -> False"` does not help for either `Export` or `ExportString` however setting it to `True` results in an even more coarsely rasterized image!

Screenshot of a section of the V11 output to show formatting:

[image]

Comment: Dunno a workaround, but I'm for marking this as a bug.

Comment: Having spoken to Wolfram this is now a known issue, introduced in 10.4 and persisting to 11.

Comment: OK, let's make it a bug then.

Comment: are all the backslashes terminating the line ends really in the mathematica string?  There are two issues here, one the result is rasterized, two the result is corrupted by being wrapped to 70 columns. The backslash is not valid postscript. That may have happened on upload to pastebin though.

Comment: @george2079, you are right the backslashes indeed appear to have happened on upload! I've posted a screenshot of the output as it appears in MMA. The length of the garbled lines appear to be fixed.

Comment: you might see if `"AllowRasterization"->False` does anything.

Comment: @george2079 Unfortunately does not help, Ive added a few more notes under EDITS.

Comment: `ImportString[ExportString[axes, "EPS"], "EPS"]` returns `$Failed` both in version 10.4.1 and 11.0.1 on Windows 7 x64 (in the both cases `ExportString` returns something similar to your [version 11 output](http://pastebin.com/A6gWQJYw)). In version 8.0.4 it works correctly.

Comment: [Jens' workaround](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/87753/280) works in version 11.0.1: `ImportString[ExportString[Graphics[Inset[axes,Automatic,Automatic,Scaled[1]]],"PDF"],"PDF"]`. But for `"EPS"` it kills the system taking all available physical memory (more than 6 GB before I killed *Mathematica.exe*)...

Answer (score 1):

Furthermore, PDF is ***not*** necessarily vector graphics.

[PostScript Language Reference, third edition, 288 ff.](https://www.adobe.com/jp/print/postscript/pdfs/PLRM.pdf) states "[a] sampled image (or just “image” for short) is a rectangular
array of sample values, each representing a color." This not vectors.

JPG does not preserve transparency and is lossful.

PNG does preserve transparency and is lossless. Furthermore, Mathematica's PNG export can preserve transpareny with an option on the export.

Although, GIF does preserve transparency, the various shades of transparency take up colors in its color table. Furthermore, Mathematica's GIF export does not support transparency.

Please, see: Transparent[How to make Mathematica graphs in Microsoft Word independent from Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38715/how-to-make-mathematica-graphs-in-microsoft-word-independent-from-mathematica)

If the purpose is to export a Graphics (or Graphics3D) as an image with a transparent background, then, please, see:

```mma
g = PolarPlot[Cos[a], {a, 0, 2*Pi}, Background -> None]
Export["temp.png", Evaluate[g], Background -> None]
png = Import["temp.png"]
Take[SortBy[Tally[Flatten[ImageData[png], 1]], -#1[[2]] & ], 3]
Export["temp.svg", g]
Import["temp.svg"]
```

Otherwise, get the InputForm of the graphic and extract the paths from it.

If the objective is to export the graphic in Mathematica form for reinport, use "MX" format, in the case of files, *file*.mx is adequate.

Lastly, Export["temp.svg", g] and extract the paths from the text file.

The SVG file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="480pt" height="460pt" viewBox="0 0 480 460" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<g id="#5879a9e3">
<path fill="#5879a9" stroke="#5879a9" stroke-width="0.09375" opacity="0.89" d=" M 29.99 1.03 L 30.86 1.08 C 30.97 3.97 31.08 6.86 31.21 9.75 C 31.74 9.74 32.79 9.71 33.31 9.69 C 32.19 11.62 30.88 13.60 30.89 15.93 C 30.62 21.19 31.01 26.47 31.18 31.73 C 31.70 31.72 32.75 31.71 33.27 31.70 C 32.18 33.64 30.91 35.62 30.90 37.93 C 30.63 43.18 31.01 48.43 31.10 53.68 C 32.85 53.99 34.60 54.30 36.35 54.63 C 34.57 54.84 32.78 55.05 31.00 55.25 C 31.03 60.52 30.66 65.80 30.91 71.07 C 30.91 73.37 32.18 75.35 33.27 77.28 C 32.75 77.28 31.70 77.28 31.18 77.28 C 31.01 82.54 30.62 87.81 30.89 93.07 C 30.88 95.40 32.19 97.38 33.31 99.31 C 32.78 99.29 31.71 99.26 31.17 99.25 C 30.81 106.07 30.81 112.90 31.16 119.72 C 31.72 119.70 32.83 119.67 33.39 119.65 C 32.40 121.34 31.09 122.99 30.99 125.03 C 30.57 130.57 31.01 136.13 31.10 141.68 C 32.85 141.98 34.60 142.29 36.35 142.62 C 34.56 142.84 32.77 143.05 30.99 143.25 C 30.89 150.08 30.83 156.92 31.17 163.74 C 31.70 163.73 32.76 163.71 33.29 163.70 C 32.18 165.63 30.89 167.61 30.90 169.93 C 30.65 175.32 31.02 180.71 31.08 186.10 C 32.23 185.96 33.38 185.83 34.53 185.70 C 37.73 167.97 43.85 150.88 51.52 134.62 C 70.85 94.15 102.89 59.88 142.01 37.93 C 161.47 26.63 182.89 19.03 204.79 14.06 C 214.07 12.12 223.49 10.98 232.90 9.93 C 247.57 8.64 262.37 9.08 276.99 10.84 C 286.66 11.83 296.23 13.64 305.60 16.23 C 343.78 25.88 379.24 46.07 406.98 74.02 C 440.49 107.10 462.63 151.37 469.35 197.95 C 471.20 208.53 471.72 219.26 471.91 229.98 C 474.60 230.01 477.30 230.04 480.00 230.07 L 480.00 230.93 C 477.31 230.96 474.62 230.98 471.94 231.01 C 471.40 244.48 470.78 258.02 468.02 271.26 C 465.25 286.46 460.50 301.23 454.70 315.53 C 448.50 329.50 441.58 343.23 432.71 355.70 C 406.76 393.64 368.55 422.97 325.25 438.34 C 309.42 443.73 293.16 448.23 276.46 449.74 C 228.89 455.50 179.60 444.98 138.36 420.64 C 115.28 406.92 94.61 389.10 77.95 368.00 C 61.90 348.02 49.65 325.07 41.29 300.87 C 38.31 292.43 36.52 283.64 34.10 275.04 C 33.33 275.02 31.81 274.96 31.04 274.94 C 31.03 280.31 30.65 285.69 30.90 291.07 C 30.89 293.39 32.18 295.37 33.29 297.30 C 32.76 297.29 31.70 297.27 31.17 297.27 C 30.83 304.12 30.86 310.99 31.05 317.85 C 32.67 317.92 34.29 318.00 35.91 318.07 L 35.90 318.93 C 34.29 319.00 32.67 319.07 31.05 319.15 C 31.02 324.45 30.64 329.76 30.91 335.07 C 30.91 337.37 32.18 339.35 33.27 341.29 C 32.75 341.29 31.70 341.28 31.17 341.27 C 30.81 348.09 30.81 354.93 31.17 361.75 C 31.70 361.74 32.78 361.70 33.31 361.69 C 29.75 366.41 30.88 372.59 30.84 378.10 C 30.76 380.73 31.94 383.10 33.26 385.29 C 32.74 385.28 31.69 385.28 31.17 385.28 C 30.82 392.13 30.85 399.00 31.05 405.86 C 32.67 405.92 34.29 406.00 35.91 406.08 L 35.92 406.93 C 34.29 407.00 32.67 407.07 31.04 407.15 C 30.86 414.01 30.82 420.88 31.17 427.74 C 31.70 427.73 32.77 427.71 33.30 427.70 C 31.93 429.87 30.73 432.25 30.84 434.90 C 30.88 440.40 29.77 446.57 33.29 451.31 C 32.78 451.29 31.76 451.27 31.25 451.26 C 31.11 453.79 30.97 456.33 30.84 458.87 L 29.99 458.97 C 30.12 388.31 29.96 317.66 30.08 247.00 C 30.08 241.71 29.90 236.42 29.74 231.14 C 27.20 231.07 24.66 231.00 22.11 230.94 L 22.10 230.06 C 24.64 229.99 27.19 229.93 29.73 229.87 C 29.88 224.58 30.07 219.29 30.08 214.00 C 29.96 143.01 30.12 72.02 29.99 1.03 M 154.90 33.75 C 105.11 57.58 65.41 101.37 46.08 153.03 C 40.11 169.27 35.44 186.10 33.62 203.35 C 32.83 212.22 32.12 221.10 31.91 230.01 C 38.52 230.10 45.14 230.07 51.75 230.00 C 51.88 229.19 52.16 227.57 52.30 226.76 C 52.65 227.80 53.00 228.85 53.34 229.91 C 60.11 230.14 66.89 230.14 73.66 229.91 C 74.00 228.86 74.35 227.80 74.69 226.75 C 74.83 227.56 75.11 229.19 75.25 230.00 C 82.08 230.09 88.91 230.09 95.75 230.00 C 95.89 229.19 96.17 227.57 96.31 226.75 C 96.65 227.80 97.00 228.86 97.35 229.91 C 104.21 230.14 111.07 230.09 117.93 229.98 C 117.98 228.34 118.02 226.71 118.07 225.08 L 118.94 225.04 C 118.98 226.68 119.02 228.34 119.06 229.99 C 125.95 230.10 132.85 230.08 139.74 230.00 C 139.88 229.19 140.16 227.57 140.30 226.76 C 140.65 227.81 141.00 228.86 141.35 229.91 C 148.11 230.14 154.89 230.14 161.65 229.91 C 162.00 228.86 162.35 227.81 162.70 226.76 C 162.84 227.57 163.12 229.19 163.26 230.00 C 170.08 230.09 176.92 230.09 183.75 230.00 C 183.88 229.19 184.16 227.56 184.30 226.75 C 184.65 227.80 185.00 228.86 185.35 229.92 C 192.21 230.13 199.07 230.10 205.94 229.99 C 205.98 228.34 206.02 226.69 206.06 225.05 L 206.93 225.06 C 206.97 226.70 207.02 228.34 207.06 229.98 C 213.96 230.11 220.85 230.07 227.74 230.00 C 227.88 229.19 228.16 227.56 228.30 226.75 C 228.65 227.80 228.99 228.86 229.34 229.91 C 236.11 230.14 242.88 230.14 249.66 229.91 C 250.00 228.86 250.34 227.80 250.70 226.76 C 250.84 227.57 251.12 229.19 251.26 230.00 C 258.09 230.09 264.91 230.09 271.74 230.00 C 271.88 229.19 272.16 227.57 272.30 226.76 C 272.65 227.81 272.99 228.86 273.34 229.91 C 280.21 230.14 287.07 230.09 293.94 229.99 C 293.98 228.33 294.02 226.68 294.06 225.03 L 294.93 225.07 C 294.97 226.71 295.02 228.34 295.07 229.99 C 301.96 230.11 308.85 230.07 315.74 230.00 C 315.88 229.19 316.16 227.57 316.30 226.76 C 316.65 227.81 316.99 228.85 317.34 229.91 C 324.11 230.14 330.89 230.14 337.66 229.91 C 338.00 228.85 338.34 227.80 338.69 226.75 C 338.83 227.57 339.12 229.19 339.26 230.00 C 346.08 230.09 352.92 230.09 359.75 230.00 C 359.88 229.18 360.16 227.55 360.29 226.73 C 360.64 227.79 360.99 228.86 361.35 229.93 C 368.21 230.12 375.07 230.10 381.94 229.98 C 381.98 228.34 382.02 226.70 382.07 225.06 L 382.94 225.05 C 382.98 226.69 383.02 228.34 383.07 229.99 C 389.96 230.11 396.85 230.08 403.74 230.00 C 403.88 229.19 404.17 227.57 404.31 226.76 C 404.65 227.81 405.00 228.86 405.35 229.92 C 412.14 230.15 418.94 230.08 425.74 230.00 C 425.88 229.19 426.16 227.56 426.30 226.75 C 426.64 227.80 426.99 228.86 427.34 229.92 C 434.11 230.14 440.89 230.14 447.66 229.91 C 448.00 228.86 448.34 227.81 448.69 226.76 C 448.83 227.57 449.12 229.19 449.26 230.00 C 455.94 230.08 462.63 230.09 469.32 230.00 C 469.85 213.73 467.71 197.49 464.20 181.64 C 460.49 166.37 455.65 151.32 448.77 137.18 C 444.72 129.04 440.70 120.85 435.68 113.26 C 429.51 103.94 423.12 94.72 415.59 86.44 C 387.58 54.28 349.97 30.60 308.86 19.28 C 282.43 11.81 254.59 10.10 227.31 12.63 C 202.24 15.59 177.47 22.34 154.90 33.75 M 30.94 186.94 C 30.81 193.36 30.93 199.79 31.47 206.19 C 31.77 199.79 32.68 193.43 34.06 187.17 C 33.28 187.11 31.72 187.00 30.94 186.94 M 31.96 230.98 C 32.01 238.44 32.17 245.92 33.26 253.32 C 36.38 285.66 47.40 317.07 64.32 344.76 C 83.72 376.16 111.00 402.80 143.30 420.76 C 153.72 427.30 165.23 431.78 176.67 436.17 C 199.86 444.35 224.37 449.15 249.00 449.05 C 265.08 449.22 281.23 447.84 296.90 444.13 C 344.18 434.15 387.76 407.73 418.62 370.57 C 436.48 349.20 450.41 324.49 458.85 297.92 C 465.81 276.36 469.78 253.69 469.32 231.00 C 323.53 230.92 177.75 230.94 31.96 230.98 M 30.98 274.02 C 31.74 274.02 33.24 274.02 33.99 274.02 C 32.63 267.37 31.71 260.62 31.50 253.83 C 30.93 260.54 30.80 267.28 30.98 274.02 Z" />
</g>
<g id="#000000d3">
<path fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.09375" opacity="0.83" d=" M 9.84 48.81 C 11.24 48.93 12.65 49.05 14.06 49.17 C 14.63 52.36 14.63 55.63 14.07 58.83 C 12.65 58.95 11.23 59.08 9.81 59.21 C 8.81 55.79 8.86 52.23 9.84 48.81 M 11.80 58.72 C 13.30 55.67 13.30 52.33 11.80 49.28 C 10.38 52.33 10.38 55.66 11.80 58.72 Z" />
<path fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.09375" opacity="0.83" d=" M 22.83 55.68 C 22.49 53.11 22.65 50.44 24.53 48.46 C 25.18 52.01 25.43 55.64 25.19 59.25 C 23.22 58.04 21.29 56.77 19.41 55.43 C 20.55 55.51 21.69 55.59 22.83 55.68 Z" />
<path fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.09375" opacity="0.83" d=" M 17.28 58.27 L 17.73 58.27 L 17.73 58.73 L 17.28 58.73 L 17.28 58.27 Z" />
<path fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.09375" opacity="0.83" d=" M 9.84 136.82 C 11.24 136.93 12.65 137.05 14.05 137.16 C 14.63 140.36 14.63 143.63 14.07 146.83 C 12.65 146.95 11.23 147.08 9.81 147.21 C 8.81 143.79 8.85 140.23 9.84 136.82 M 11.11 137.44 C 10.55 140.55 10.62 143.75 11.77 146.72 C 12.34 144.65 13.50 142.51 12.97 140.31 C 12.41 139.32 11.79 138.36 11.11 137.44 Z" />
<path fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.09375" opacity="0.83" d=" M 19.41 138.31 C 21.39 137.63 24.46 135.71 25.77 138.40 C 26.48 141.39 23.68 143.53 22.13 145.72 C 23.57 146.07 25.00 146.44 26.43 146.82 C 23.27 146.95 20.11 147.00 16.95 147.07 C 18.80 145.92 20.76 144.89 22.30 143.32 C 23.43 141.89 23.83 140.05 24.50 138.39 C 22.80 138.37 21.11 138.35 19.41 138.31 Z" />
<path fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.09375" opacity="0.83" d=" M 110.93 236.03 C 112.32 236.03 113.71 236.03 115.10 236.03 C 115.99 239.46 115.94 243.01 114.94 246.41 C 113.53 246.04 112.12 245.70 110.77 245.18 C 109.24 242.32 110.53 239.01 110.93 236.03 M 111.92 237.79 C 111.92 239.93 111.92 242.07 111.92 244.21 C 112.46 244.21 113.53 244.21 114.07 244.21 C 114.07 242.07 114.07 239.93 114.07 237.79 C 113.54 237.79 112.46 237.79 111.92 237.79 Z" />
<path fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.09375" opacity="0.83" d=" M 120.43 237.38 C 122.51 236.48 124.74 236.07 127.00 235.99 C 127.44 239.60 125.39 242.50 123.01 244.94 C 124.33 244.97 125.65 245.01 126.97 245.06 L 127.08 246.16 C 124.95 246.05 122.83 245.94 120.70 245.83 C 122.17 243.82 123.67 241.83 125.18 239.85 C 125.18 239.21 125.18 237.94 125.18 237.30 C 123.60 237.34 122.01 237.37 120.43 237.38 Z" />
<path fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.09375" opacity="0.83" d=" M 198.92 236.03 C 200.31 236.03 201.70 236.03 203.10 236.03 C 203.99 239.45 203.94 243.01 202.94 246.41 C 201.54 246.04 200.12 245.70 198.77 245.18 C 197.25 242.33 198.53 239.02 198.92 236.03 M 199.92 237.79 C 199.92 239.93 199.93 242.07 199.93 244.21 C 200.47 244.21 201.54 244.21 202.07 244.22 C 202.07 242.07 202.07 239.93 202.07 237.79 C 201.53 237.79 200.46 237.79 199.92 237.79 Z" />
<path fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.09375" opacity="0.83" d=" M 209.65 242.02 C 210.86 239.76 212.24 237.59 213.84 235.58 C 214.41 238.99 214.64 242.45 214.46 245.91 C 212.59 244.97 210.71 244.04 208.85 243.10 C 210.11 242.88 211.38 242.67 212.65 242.47 C 212.81 241.38 212.96 240.31 213.13 239.23 C 211.98 240.17 210.82 241.10 209.65 242.02 Z" />
<path fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.09375" opacity="0.83" d=" M 286.92 236.03 C 288.31 236.03 289.70 236.03 291.10 236.03 C 291.99 239.45 291.94 243.01 290.93 246.42 C 289.53 246.04 288.13 245.70 286.78 245.18 C 285.25 242.33 286.53 239.01 286.92 236.03 M 287.92 237.78 C 287.92 239.92 287.92 242.07 287.93 244.22 C 288.47 244.22 289.54 244.21 290.08 244.21 C 290.07 242.07 290.07 239.93 290.07 237.79 C 289.54 237.79 288.46 237.78 287.92 237.78 Z" />
<path fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.09375" opacity="0.83" d=" M 299.35 236.02 C 300.74 236.11 302.09 236.50 303.45 236.84 C 301.86 237.28 300.27 237.69 298.70 238.19 C 300.52 239.94 302.52 241.50 304.48 243.10 C 302.73 244.85 300.57 246.05 298.10 246.39 C 297.36 243.01 295.79 238.41 299.35 236.02 M 299.34 240.46 C 299.29 242.17 299.28 243.88 299.29 245.59 C 300.15 244.60 301.91 243.98 301.68 242.41 C 300.92 241.73 300.14 241.08 299.34 240.46 Z" />
<path fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.09375" opacity="0.83" d=" M 374.86 235.87 C 376.25 235.95 377.63 236.04 379.03 236.13 C 379.77 239.34 379.78 242.65 379.03 245.87 C 377.64 245.95 376.25 246.05 374.86 246.14 C 373.91 242.77 373.89 239.24 374.86 235.87 M 376.16 236.42 C 375.86 239.47 375.86 242.53 376.16 245.58 C 377.01 244.15 378.35 242.80 378.18 241.00 C 378.35 239.20 377.01 237.85 376.16 236.42 Z" />
<path fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.09375" opacity="0.83" d=" M 385.67 235.92 C 387.32 236.03 388.97 236.16 390.63 236.30 C 390.75 237.52 390.87 238.75 391.00 239.98 C 390.55 240.05 389.65 240.19 389.20 240.26 C 389.08 239.34 388.83 237.49 388.71 236.57 C 387.77 237.84 386.82 239.11 385.88 240.38 C 385.79 238.89 385.72 237.40 385.67 235.92 Z" />
<path fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.09375" opacity="0.83" d=" M 463.23 238.10 C 464.35 237.33 465.48 236.56 466.62 235.81 C 466.85 239.39 467.08 243.07 465.79 246.50 C 465.20 243.63 464.53 240.75 463.23 238.10 Z" />
<path fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.09375" opacity="0.83" d=" M 473.94 236.02 C 475.32 236.02 476.71 236.02 478.11 236.03 C 478.98 239.46 478.93 243.01 477.95 246.42 C 476.21 245.70 473.51 245.95 472.88 243.76 C 472.15 241.15 473.35 238.53 473.94 236.02 M 474.93 237.79 C 474.92 239.93 474.92 242.07 474.92 244.21 C 475.46 244.21 476.54 244.22 477.08 244.22 C 477.07 242.07 477.07 239.93 477.07 237.79 C 476.54 237.79 475.46 237.79 474.93 237.79 Z" />
<path fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.09375" opacity="0.83" d=" M 389.69 240.55 C 390.57 241.41 391.44 242.27 392.33 243.13 C 391.19 244.07 390.26 245.40 388.82 245.91 C 387.50 245.78 386.20 245.45 384.92 245.16 C 385.23 244.15 385.55 243.14 385.88 242.13 C 386.84 243.20 387.81 244.28 388.83 245.31 C 389.17 243.73 389.43 242.14 389.69 240.55 Z" />
<path fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.09375" opacity="0.83" d=" M 118.25 245.09 L 118.97 244.68 L 119.68 245.09 L 119.68 245.91 L 118.96 246.33 L 118.25 245.91 L 118.25 245.09 Z" />
<path fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.09375" opacity="0.83" d=" M 206.25 245.09 L 206.97 244.68 L 207.68 245.09 L 207.68 245.92 L 206.96 246.33 L 206.25 245.91 L 206.25 245.09 Z" />
<path fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.09375" opacity="0.83" d=" M 294.25 245.09 L 294.96 244.68 L 295.68 245.08 L 295.68 245.91 L 294.97 246.32 L 294.25 245.92 L 294.25 245.09 Z" />
<path fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.09375" opacity="0.83" d=" M 382.25 245.08 L 382.97 244.67 L 383.68 245.09 L 383.68 245.91 L 382.96 246.32 L 382.25 245.91 L 382.25 245.08 Z" />
<path fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.09375" opacity="0.83" d=" M 9.15 313.09 C 10.46 313.06 11.76 313.03 13.07 313.01 C 14.02 316.45 13.96 320.03 12.87 323.43 C 9.14 321.55 5.29 319.74 1.03 319.67 L 1.03 319.04 C 3.27 318.98 5.51 318.92 7.75 318.86 C 8.21 316.93 8.68 315.01 9.15 313.09 M 9.93 314.78 C 9.93 316.92 9.93 319.07 9.93 321.22 C 10.46 321.22 11.54 321.21 12.08 321.21 C 12.08 319.07 12.08 316.93 12.07 314.79 C 11.54 314.79 10.47 314.79 9.93 314.78 Z" />
<path fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.09375" opacity="0.83" d=" M 18.43 314.39 C 20.51 313.49 22.75 313.07 25.01 312.99 C 25.44 316.59 23.40 319.51 21.01 321.94 C 22.33 321.97 23.65 322.01 24.97 322.06 L 25.08 323.16 C 22.96 323.05 20.83 322.94 18.71 322.83 C 20.17 320.82 21.67 318.83 23.17 316.85 C 23.18 316.21 23.18 314.93 23.18 314.29 C 21.60 314.34 20.01 314.37 18.43 314.39 Z" />
<path fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.09375" opacity="0.83" d=" M 16.25 322.09 L 16.96 321.67 L 17.68 322.09 L 17.68 322.91 L 16.96 323.32 L 16.25 322.91 L 16.25 322.09 Z" />
<path fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.09375" opacity="0.83" d=" M 9.15 401.09 C 10.45 401.06 11.76 401.03 13.07 401.01 C 14.02 404.44 13.96 408.03 12.87 411.43 C 9.14 409.55 5.29 407.73 1.02 407.67 L 1.04 407.05 C 3.28 406.98 5.52 406.93 7.75 406.86 C 8.21 404.93 8.68 403.01 9.15 401.09 M 9.93 402.79 C 9.92 404.92 9.92 407.06 9.92 409.20 C 10.46 409.21 11.53 409.21 12.07 409.22 C 12.07 407.07 12.07 404.93 12.07 402.79 C 11.54 402.79 10.46 402.79 9.93 402.79 Z" />
<path fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.09375" opacity="0.83" d=" M 19.65 407.01 C 20.87 404.76 22.25 402.59 23.84 400.58 C 24.41 403.99 24.63 407.45 24.46 410.91 C 22.59 409.97 20.72 409.04 18.85 408.10 C 20.12 407.88 21.38 407.67 22.65 407.47 C 22.81 406.39 22.97 405.31 23.13 404.24 C 21.98 405.17 20.82 406.10 19.65 407.01 Z" />
<path fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.09375" opacity="0.83" d=" M 16.25 410.09 L 16.96 409.68 L 17.68 410.09 L 17.68 410.91 L 16.97 411.33 L 16.25 410.92 L 16.25 410.09 Z" />
</g>
</svg>
```

Of course, I may have missed something.