# How can I insert an EPS file exported from RegionPlot into MS Word?

Tags: graphics, export, interoperability, eps-format, office

I generate a figure using `RegionPlot` and then `Export` it as `"EPS"`. When I insert this picture into MS Word, it doesn't work.

The figure is generated by the following code:

```
Constraint1[α1_, α2_] := Cos[α2] (Sin[α2]/Sin[α1] - Sin[α2] Cot[α1] + Cos[α2]);

CSSSS = Show[
  RegionPlot[
   0 < α1 < α2 < 60 && Constraint1[α1*π/180, α2*π/180] > 1/2, 
   {α1, 0, 59.999}, {α2, 0, 60},
   BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> Times, 25}, ImageSize -> 600,
   FrameLabel -> {Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(α\), \(1\)]\)(\[Degree])", 28], 
                  Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(α\), \(2\)]\)(\[Degree])", 28]},
   PlotLabel -> Style["Value Range of Basic Angles", 25, Black],
   FrameStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.003], Black],
   Epilog -> {Inset[Style["(45, 60)", 25], {40, 59}], 
              Inset[Style["(45, 50)", 25], {50, 49}], 
              Inset[Style["(40, 50)", 25], {35, 49}]}],
  ListPlot[{{45, 60}, {45, 50}, {40, 50}}, PlotStyle -> Red]]

Export["xxx.eps", CSSSS]
```

Screenshot after importing the "xxx.eps" file into MS Word:

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: You are missing the `ticksFig1DX` and `ticksFig1DY` functions in your question.

Comment: For several versions now, I've been able to select the graphics in *Mathematica*, copy it, and paste it into Word.  I don't know what image format is used, but it appears to be vector graphics (PDF?).

Comment: To copy and past the graphics seems to produce a bitmap, “Export” it to particular format (including PDF) can get the wanted format, but sometimes "eps" cannot be inserted to Word.@Jack Lavigne

Comment: You could also select the figure and choose Edit->Copy As->Metafile. It pastes well into Word or PowerPoint and it is a vector format.

Comment: @GustavoDelfino About drawbacks of Edit->Copy As->Metafile:  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/60972/280

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Thanks for the info. I guess it depends on the final objective. In my environment we almost never print.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The figure you are trying to `Export` into EPS format contains semi-transparent objects unsupported by this format:

```
Cases[CSSSS, _Opacity, Infinity]
```

> ```
> {Opacity[0.3]}
> ```

Actually all the filling produced by `RegionPlot` is semi-transparent as you can easily find using my [`shortInputForm` function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55545/280):

```
CSSSS // shortInputForm
```

Since transparency actually isn't necessary for your image you can simply replace default semi-transparent filling with non-transparent color (which exactly reproduces the default styling) by adding the following option to `RegionPlot`:

```
PlotStyle -> RGBColor[0.8105251`, 0.8520337`, 0.9129394`]
```

Now

```
Cases[CSSSS, _Opacity, Infinity]
```

> ```
> {Opacity[1]}
> ```

while the plot looks exactly as it was looking originally.

In the general case when you have semi-transparent objects overlapping with some non-uniform background you have to perform *transparency flattening*, see [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32948/280) for details.

However even after removing transparency MS Word still cannot import the EPS file `Export`ed from *Mathematica* 10.2 (which I currently work with, but the same is true for version 8.0.4). The most probable reason is that this EPS file contains PostScript Level 3 instructions which MS Office EPS Import Filter cannot understand. In [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/650524/71768) I discuss limitations of the latter and known methods allowing to generate EPS files compatible with MS Office. The most reliable way is to `Export` as PDF from *Mathematica*, then use free utility `pdftops` or `pdftocairo` from [Poppler utilities for Windows](https://github.com/oschwartz10612/poppler-windows) for generating Level 2 EPS file as follows:

```
pdftops -level2 -eps input.pdf
pdftocairo -level2 -eps input.pdf
```

Following the `pdftocairo` route I obtain EPS file which MS Word 2003 successfully imports producing the following visual appearance in Word:

[image: screenshot]

As you can see, the Greek letters `α` are not displayed and instead of Times it displays all text as Arial. But what you see is not the actual imported figure: it is just a preview automatically generated by MS Office EPS Import filter which is known to be inaccurate. For the purposes of printing to PostScript printers this preview isn't used by Word: it sends original PostScript code to the PostScript printers (this code is embedded into Word document when you import a EPS file but cannot be displayed because Word cannot render PostScript). The preview is used only for display purposes and for printing to non-PostScript printers. Let us try to print this Word document to the "Adobe PDF" virtual printer and check how generated PDF file looks in Adobe Acrobat:

[image: screenshot]

The figure looks perfectly and the glyph `α` is correctly embedded!

---

If you are not satisfied with the above result you have to go through the Adobe Illustrator route described in the [linked answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32948/280): import the PDF file `Export`ed from *Mathematica* into Illustrator, edit it in order to fix incorrectly imported text, then export as EPS with [**unchecked** option  "Include CMYK PostScript in RGB Files"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GTkV.png). From my experience, EPS files exported from Illustrator this way are always previewed correctly in MS Word.

Answer (score 2):

I find that using JPEG makes a small file on disk that Word accepts. Another possibility is BMP. This is large on disk but the resulting Word file is not any larger than the JPEG Word file.

```
Export["xxx.JPEG", CSSSS]
Export["xxx.BMP", CSSSS]
```

[image: Word]

Comment: Thanks, "JPEG" or "BMP" is a good choice, while before I wanted to get a vector graphics!

Comment: Actually JPG is a bad choice for line-type graphics because it is lossy format which introduces artifacts. For line-type graphics PNG format is always preferable: it is lossless and in many cases produces even smaller files than JPG because this format is specifically intended for encoding line-type graphics!